Is there a bug in tcolorbox with `\tcb\ams align`?
I try to use the option keys /tcb/ams align and /tcb/ams gather (and alike) from the theorems library in a tcolorbox.
If there is no lower part all is ok! But with a lower part there is an issue!
I know that I can just not using the option key and put the align environment inside the body of the tcolorbox but I want to figure out if it is not just me who have missed something.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

% /tcb/ams equation --> ok!
\begin{tcolorbox}[ams equation]
\alpha=\beta
\tcblower
\theta=\gamma
\end{tcolorbox}

% /tcb/ams align with no lower part --> ok!
\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align]
\alpha=\beta\\
\theta=\gamma\\
a=b\\
c=d
\end{tcolorbox}

% /tcb/ams align with lower part --> faillure!!!
\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align]
\alpha&=\beta\\
\theta&=\gamma
\tcblower 
a&=b\\
c&=d
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document} 



Might be an idea to add an image as well

@daleif good idea!

hm, imho what tcolorbox is doing here can not work. align can not collect the upper and lower part separately with the code used. Instead it collects the whole content \alpha &=\beta \\ \theta &=\gamma \tcblower a&=b\\ c&=d  and when it processes that it falls over the included \tcblower. You should report that.

To support what @UlrikeFischer said: it appears that \begin{tcolorbox}[ams align upper] a &  b \tcblower Text \end{tcolorbox} doesn't work, but \begin{tcolorbox}[ams align lower] Text \tcblower a& b \end{tcolorbox} does work.

@WillieWong Yes but ams equation does work with \tcblower

equation is defined differently to align, it doesn't try to collect its body.

@UlrikeFischer see mbert's answer.

In the tcolorbox documentation it says

Boxes with /tcb/ams align upper or /tcb/ams align cannot have a lower part! For a lower part, use /tcb/ams nodisplayskip upper instead.

So here's your example with ams nodisplayskip (applies to both upper and lower parts).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams equation]
\alpha=\beta
\tcblower
\theta=\gamma
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align]
\alpha=\beta\\
\theta=\gamma\\
a=b\\
c=d
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams nodisplayskip]
\begin{align}
\alpha&=\beta\\
\theta&=\gamma
\end{align}
\tcblower
\begin{align}
a&=b\\
c&=d
\end{align}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}



As  I said in the question: I know that I can just not using the option key and put the align environment inside the body of the tcolorbox but I want to figure out if it is not just me who have missed something.

@HafidBoukhoulda I am confused by your comment. My reference to the documentation implies yes, you (and surely others) missed a documented limitation. Please feel free to clarify

@HafidBoukhoulda Ah I see your issue spurred the addition of that warning to the doc
